# Loop for nc code and arrange data row wise

Tags: r, loops, csv, netcdf, netcdf4

I have the following code for nc files. This code makes individual csv file for all the netcdf files present in my working directory. It arranges the data row wise. It skips longitude and latitude and even name or serial number and replaces it V1, V2 and so on.

Can anyone help me out that why it is not including latitude/longitude or even serial number and why it is showing top row as V1, V2, V3?

How can I get the data of all the nc files in 1 single csv file. I mean single csv output file should contain top (1st) row of csv for header (station names or serial numbers or if even V1, V2, ...) and 2nd row for 1st nc file data, 3rd row for 2nd nc file data, 4th row for 3rd nc file data and so on.

I have attached pictures of  input csv having coordinates and 1 single csv output for 1 nc file.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

setwd("F:\\research\\1_Rainfall\\CDC\\test")
files <- list.files(pattern="*.nc")
print(files)
ncname <- files[1:3]
ncfname <- paste(ncname, sep="")

library(raster)

dname <- "precip"  # note: variable precipitation or temperature

for(i in 1:3){
  ncin1 <- brick(ncfname[i])
  s = read.csv("F:\\research\\1_Rainfall\\CDC\\test\\Remaining_Points.csv", 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  coordinates(s)= ~lon + lat 
  e <- extract(ncin1, s)

  ts1 <- round((e),1)
  df <- as.data.frame(t(ts1))

  write.csv(df, 
            file = paste0("F:\\research\\1_Rainfall\\CDC\\test\\precip", i, ".csv"), 
            append=FALSE, sep= ",", row.names = TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a simple reproducible example when you ask a question. And try to break up your question into parts. You have two questions (1) how to store the data you extract row-wise, and (2) how to append to a file. I will answer #1 as you may not need #2.

```
files <- rep(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"), 3)
xy <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
stations <- letters[1:nrow(xy)]

d <- data.frame(t(xy))
colnames(d) <- station
d <- cbind(file="", var=c("x", "y"), d)
     
for(i in 1:length(files)){
    nc <- brick(files[i])
    e <- t(extract(nc, xy))
    colnames(e) <- stations
    v <- data.frame(file=basename(files[i]), var=names(nc), e)
    d <- rbind(d, v)
}
rownames(d) <- NULL
d
write.csv(d, outf)
```

Your code, cleaned up a bit, could look like this:

library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.nc")
library(raster)
s <- read.csv("Remaining_Points.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy <- s[, c("lon", "lat")]
stations <- s$stationname

for(i in 1:length(files)){
  nc <- brick(files[i])
  e <- t(round(extract(nc, xy), 1))

  # etc
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have nc files of precipitation on daily basis for a year. The code which I have written extracts values using coordinates (csv file) and outputs csv file on daily basis having top row as V1, V2, V3 and second row as values. Here V1, V2, V3 represents stations (coordinates)
I want that the output should be single csv file having top row as V1, V2, V3 and in the next rows of csv there should be data. Means in row 2 there should be data of 1st nc file and row 3 there should be data of 2nd nc file....... in row 366 there should be values of 365th nc file. I want single csv output, please.

Comment: Sir, I have tried this one

files <- list.files(pattern="*.nc")
library(raster)
s <- read.csv("Remaining_Points.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy <- s[, c("lon", "lat")]
stations <- s$stationname

for(i in 1:length(files)){
  nc <- brick(files[i])
  e <- t(round(extract(nc, xy), 1))

  # etc
}

it is very good but the only problem is ther, 
 it provides single csv file for each nc file.
Please guide me how to get output of all the nc file in same csv file in consecutive columns, please